# c# visual studio .Inserted values dont show up on the table

Tags: c#, database, insert

I´ve Created a simple register forms project and with 2 textboxes and a confirm button aswell as a database with one table. When I press the button  the values in the textboxes should be inserted into the table,however nothing shows up on the table everything is nulled. It would be very helpful if someone could show me what I did wrong.
Im sorry if this has been asked too much but I try to fix this for a long time now.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Btnregister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Shopdatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into logindata (Accountname, Passwort) values(@acct,@pass)", con);           
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acct", acctxtregister.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pwregister.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Registrierung Erfolgreich");

    }
```

This is the code for the table I use in my database:

```sql
      CREATE TABLE [dbo].[logindata] (
    [Id]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Accountname] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Passwort]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Your table name is `Table`, not `logindata`.

Comment: Your code should throw an exception after this line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); due to logindata table doesn't exist as @GabrielNegut said. It's this happening?

Comment: no I pasted the wrong table code my table code is :                                   
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[logindata] (
    [Id]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Accountname] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Passwort]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Comment: Are you 100% certain you are looking at the correct database? You should be getting an exception if anything goes wrong with the insertion.

Comment: Another possibility is the event handler is not subscribed correctly. Place a breakpoint somewhere in `Btnregister_Click` to confirm it's called when you click the button.

Comment: @GabrielNegut thats the thing I dont get normally when I get problems it refers to my execution command but nope everything works but my table is empty I pulled the database from app.config btw,this problem occured earlier with another project which infact worked before I think my visual studio has some problems is there any way to see if I installed the correct addons?

Comment: You don't need any addons. Check to see if the method is invoked when clicking the button, and if it is, try using the absolute path to `Shopdatabase.mdf` (instead of `|DataDirectory\Shopdatabase.mdf`) to confirm you're looking at the correct file.